# How to use PostCSS with npm script only (No Gulp, Webpack or Grunt)

Tags: json, node.js, package.json, postcss, npm-scripts

I found tutorials like this: https://medium.com/heresy-dev/getting-started-with-postcss-a-quick-guide-for-sass-users-90c8b675d5f4

(I must really wonder how less i find on the internet about the use of a postcss.json config file.)

and this one: https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-postcss/

But all those tutorials didnt worked for me. I use the latest version of postcss and postcss-cli. When i start this script:

```
"postcss": "postcss --config postcss.json"
```

then i just get a error:

> Input Error: Did not receive any STDIN

When i google for this, i also dont find any solution that helps me.

My package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postcss": "postcss --config postcss.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss": "^6.0.13",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-colormin": "^2.2.2",
  }
}
```

My postcss.json:

```
{
  "use": [
    "autoprefixer"
  ],
  "input": "public_html/css/",
  "output": "public_html/css/min/*.css",
  "local-plugins": true,
  "watch": false
}
```